# Code-first migration in Entity Framework Core error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am a .NET student. So please be patient with me. Apart from adding this question here I search web tirelessly to find a solution to my problem. Thank you for understanding.

I am trying to migrate a code-first project with Entity Framework Core just so I can familiarize my self with all the commands and procedures.

The problem I am getting is when a try to migrate. I am writing the line

```
add-migration Initial-Migration -context BlogContext
```

in the Package Manager Console. The error I am getting is this one:

[image: Error message]

These are my dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
```

Tell me if there is anything more you would like to see. I am grateful for all the help I get.

EDIT:

My BlogContext:
[image: BlogContext]

New error from VS Package manager Console:

[image]

Comment: This may not be a problem with your migration.  If you have build errors it won't migrate.  The first thing I would try is to clean and build your project.

Comment: The project builds and runs without any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",` dependency (line 3 in listing) - it's old version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and it may add some old/undesired libs to you app
2. Run `dotnet restore` from command line (from `src/Blogg` folder) to refresh package list (VS should do it automatically, but we need to be sure).
3. Manually remove `bin` and `obj` folders
4. Run `dotnet ef migrations add BlogContext` from command line (from `src/Blogg` folder)

Comment: `code`GenericArguments[0], 'Blogg.Migrations.BlogContext', on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'.

Comment: Oops, after step 1 - did you (or VS automatically) restored packages? Force this by running `dotnet restore` (updated my answer with this step). With new error - if your run `add-migration` from Package Manager Console - you will receive new error too? Or old one? If new, then show your `BlogContext` class.

Comment: After deleting the line in dependencies I saved. Bur ran a restore from the CMD. Still the sam message after dotnet ef migration command. But in visual studio I got a migrations folder with BlogContextModelSnapshot.cs and 20161221133817_BlogContext.cs. Cant find the database in SSMS thou. Updated my question with a pic of my BlogContext. Thanks for the patiance. I managed to do code first and database first in old EF, but now I feel like I am att the bottom of the jar again.

Comment: I also ran the add-migration in VS Package Manager Console. Updated my question with the new error.

Comment: You can remove files from `Migrations` folder and create them again - real DB not involved. To update database, you need `dotnet ef database update` in cmd or `Update-Database` [in PM Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell). EF tooling is still in preview and some bug are... possible :) But I don't understand source/nature of new error, never see it before. Does project compiles now (with migrations?).

Comment: The project compiles and runs with the new migrations. Am I supposedto be able to rache the

Comment: Sorry. sentence was supposed to end at new migrations

Comment: One more thing. You use packages 1.1.0, and `Microsoft.NETCore.App` 1.1.0, but on second screenshot I see "NetCoreApp v1.0" - what are your `frameworks` section of `project.json`? It should be `netcoreapp1.1` there...

Comment: Yes your right, I hade "netcoreapp1.0". changed it to  "netcoreapp1.1" Saved/updated. VS Restored package. Ran ef migration commnads  from package manager. Still error. Changed back to "NetCoreApp v1.0."  Saved/updated. VS Restored package. Ran ef migration commads again from package manager. Belive it or not the whole process succeded. Migration folder was created with files and the actual database now exist. Now I just have to recreate everything without a glitch. LuckilyI took notes. But still. Thank you very much for your patience and help. Much appreciated!!